# Cacher with HashMap

Tags: rust

As recommended in Chapter 13.1, i tried to implement a Cacher using HashMap:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Cacher<T, U> 
where
    T: Fn(U) -> U,
    U: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<U, U>,
}

impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U> 
where
    T: Fn(U) -> U,
    U: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy,
{
    pub fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &U{
        self.values.entry(arg).or_insert((self.calculation)(arg))
    }
}
```

But running the following Code:

```
use cacher::Cacher;

fn main() {
    let mut cacher = Cacher::new(|arg|{
        println!("Executing for {:?}", arg);
        arg
    });
    assert_eq!(cacher.value(1), &1);
    assert_eq!(cacher.value(2), &2);
    assert_eq!(cacher.value(3), &3);
    assert_eq!(cacher.value(1), &1);
    assert_eq!(cacher.value(2), &2);
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
   Compiling cacher v0.1.0 (C:\Users\felix\Programming\rust\projects\Cacher)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.67s
     Running `target\debug\cacher.exe`
Executing for 1
Executing for 2
Executing for 3
Executing for 1
Executing for 2
```

Showing that the Cacher doesn't work, executing calculation for every call to value, even for known args.
What went wrong in the value function

Comment: @interjay https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40ebb47bbecac56d1cb3844249d914ea or https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2cebfb980e7ee2944b50e625f1b682ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the function is being called even if the key already exists.

The code for `fn value(&mut self, arg: U)` do the same of the code below:

```rust
pub fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &U {
    let placeholder = (self.calculation)(arg);
    self.values.entry(arg).or_insert(placeholder)
}
```

---

So, instead, you could use the method [`.or_insert_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with), which allows you to pass a function that will be called only if the key doesn't exist, as shown in [the playground posted in the comments](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2cebfb980e7ee2944b50e625f1b682ca):

```rust
pub fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &U {
    let calculation = &self.calculation;
    self.values.entry(arg).or_insert_with(|| calculation(arg))
}
```